# How to return ReturnSchema or Null from UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark UDF in Scala as follows and trying to return either a Schema or null:

```
case class ReturnSchema(a: String, b: String,c: String, d: java.sql.Timestamp)

val myUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf((abc: java.sql.Timestamp, xyz1: Seq[Row]) => {

    xyz1.map(xyz=>{
        val a = xyz.getAs[String](fieldName = "a")
        val b = xyz.getAs[String](fieldName = "b")
        val c = xyz.getAs[String](fieldName = "c")
        val d = xyz.getAs[java.sql.Timestamp](fieldName = "d")
        val timeDifferenceInMilliSeconds: Long = d.getTime - abc.getTime
        val timeDifferenceInMinutes = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(timeDifferenceInMilliSeconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        if(timeDifferenceInMinutes >= 15) {
            val myReturn = ReturnSchema(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d)
            Option(myReturn)
        }

    })
})
```

If the condition isn't satisfied I want to return None. If satisfied return the ReturnSchema. On suggestion of using Option, I tried and received : Schema for type Any is not supported.

Comment: Don't use `null` in Scala. We have `Option` types just for this purpose

Comment: How do I return options instead? Since schema for type any is not supported?

Comment: UDFs can return `Option` so in this case `Option[ReturnSchema]`

Comment: I tried this: `val xyz = ReturnSchema(a = a, b = b, c = c)` and returned 
                `Option(xyz)` and got `Schema for type Any is not supported`

Comment: Please update the question with a minimal reproducible example. It is impossible to say what you are doing wrong through pseudo code

Comment: @sinanspd Updated.

Comment: You only have one branch of the If statement. You aren't returning anything if the condition doesn't pass. So you are returning `Option` in the if branch, `Unit` otherwise which gets cast to `Any` as that is the least upper bound of those two. You need to return `Some(myResult)` in the if case, `None` otherwise

Comment: Got it! That worked! Thank you so much. I just need one more help. Now my xyz1 column has rows which are two dimensional sequences(lists of lists) so when I return None for each of the list in lists of lists I still get output as [,,]. Is there anyway from this UDF I can return the whole list of lists as None?

Comment: So you want to return `None` if it is `List(None, None, ... None)`, `List[ReturnSchema]` otherwise? What happens if only some of the elements are `None` and some are not?

Comment: Then I want to return only non None values.

Comment: `List.flatten` will remove the None values. I recommend taking some time to actually learn Scala before diving into Spark. You can go through a basic intro tutorial over a weekend and wouldn't have any of these issues

Comment: Will do. I was given a task with deadline and hence had to rush. But will definitely invest time in learning. Thank you for the help :)